# Remove the categories column from finalfit::or_plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am making some logistic regression, and my goal is to find a graphic way to represent the ORs.
I found the function or_plot from the finalfit package. But i want to remove the column with all the categories names.

With an example on the data iris:

```
data(iris)
library(finalfit)
library(dplyr)

iris <- iris %>%
  mutate(setosa_on = ifelse(Species=="setosa", 1, 0),
         sl_5 = ifelse(Sepal.Length>5, ">5", "<= 5"))
iris %>%
  or_plot("setosa_on", "sl_5",
          plot_opts=xlab("OR, 95% CI"),
          remove_ref=TRUE)
```

[image: Result from the or_plot function]

Between the variable name, and the OR(IC, p), there is the name of the corresponding category, and i want to remove this column for the entire plot. I found how to remove the ref line, but not the categories names.
Or if by any chance there is a more flexible and automatic function (like not typing all the ORs manually)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible in the current function.  The `or_plot()` function internally builds a data frame (`df.out`) that it uses to plot.  That data frame looks like this:

```r
#      fit_id label levels      unit     value Total index        OR (multivariable)                 OR         L95        U95            p
# 1 sl_5<= 5  sl_5   <= 5 Mean (sd) 0.9 (0.3)    32     1                         -                1.0          NA         NA           NA
# 2   sl_5>5           >5 Mean (sd) 0.2 (0.4)   118     2 0.03 (0.01-0.09, p<0.001) 0.0327380952394317 0.008980347 0.09340157 4.906832e-09
```

It then builds the plot with the annotations using the following code:

```r
t1 = ggplot(df.out, aes(x = as.numeric(OR), y = fit_id)) + 
  annotate("text", x = column_space[1], y = df.out$fit_id, 
           label = df.out[, 2], hjust = 0, size = table_text_size) + 
  annotate("text", x = column_space[2], y = df.out$fit_id, 
           label = df.out[, 3], hjust = 1, size = table_text_size) + 
  annotate("text", x = column_space[3], y = df.out$fit_id, 
           label = df.out[, 8], hjust = 1, size = table_text_size) + 
  theme_classic(14) + theme(axis.title.x = element_text(colour = "white"), 
                            axis.text.x = element_text(colour = "white"), axis.title.y = element_blank(), 
                            axis.text.y = element_blank(), axis.ticks.y = element_blank(), 
                            line = element_blank())
```

The first `annotate()` call puts the label in, the second `annotate()` call puts the factor levels in (i.e., what you're trying to get rid of) and the third one adds the OR (CI, p) to the plot.  These size of the texts are all controlled by the same parameter `table_text_size`, so it's not possible to make one of them 0 and leave the others.  They also do not have color parameters (so you couldn't set the color of the one you don't want to the background color).  There also does not seem to be a way to shut off printing any one of those - they all always print.

You could modify the function so it turns off that one printed column.

```r
my_orplot <- function (.data, dependent, explanatory, random_effect = NULL, 
          factorlist = NULL, glmfit = NULL, confint_type = NULL, remove_ref = FALSE, 
          breaks = NULL, column_space = c(-0.5, 0, 0.5), dependent_label = NULL, 
          prefix = "", suffix = ": OR (95% CI, p-value)", table_text_size = 4, 
          title_text_size = 13, plot_opts = NULL, table_opts = NULL, print_level=FALSE,
          ...) {
  require(finalfit)
  require(ggplot2)
  if (!is.null(factorlist)) {
    if (is.null(factorlist$Total)) 
      stop("summary_factorlist function must include total_col=TRUE")
    if (is.null(factorlist$fit_id)) 
      stop("summary_factorlist function must include fit_id=TRUE")
  }
  if (is.null(factorlist)) {
    factorlist = finalfit:::summary_factorlist(.data, dependent, explanatory, 
                                    total_col = TRUE, fit_id = TRUE)
  }
  if (remove_ref) {
    factorlist = factorlist %>% dplyr::mutate(label = ifelse(label == 
                                                               "", NA, label)) %>% tidyr::fill(label) %>% dplyr::group_by(label) %>% 
      dplyr::filter(dplyr::row_number() != 1 | dplyr::n() > 
                      2 | levels %in% c("Mean (SD)", "Median (IQR)")) %>% 
      finalfit::rm_duplicate_labels()
  }
  if (is.null(breaks)) {
    breaks = scales::pretty_breaks()
  }
  if (is.null(confint_type) && is.null(random_effect)) {
    confint_type = "profile"
  }else if (is.null(confint_type) && (!is.null(random_effect) | 
                                     inherits(glmfit, "glmerMod"))) {
    confint_type = "default"
  }
  if (is.null(glmfit) && is.null(random_effect)) {
    glmfit = glmmulti(.data, dependent, explanatory)
    glmfit_df_c = fit2df(glmfit, condense = TRUE, estimate_suffix = " (multivariable)", 
                         confint_type = confint_type, ...)
  }else if (is.null(glmfit) && !is.null(random_effect)) {
    glmfit = glmmixed(.data, dependent, explanatory, random_effect)
    glmfit_df_c = fit2df(glmfit, condense = TRUE, estimate_suffix = " (multilevel)", 
                         confint_type = confint_type, ...)
  }
  if (!is.null(glmfit) && is.null(random_effect)) {
    glmfit_df_c = fit2df(glmfit, condense = TRUE, estimate_suffix = " (multivariable)", 
                         confint_type = confint_type, estimate_name = "OR", 
                         exp = TRUE, ...)
  }else if (!is.null(glmfit) && !is.null(random_effect)) {
    glmfit_df_c = fit2df(glmfit, condense = TRUE, estimate_suffix = " (multilevel)", 
                         confint_type = confint_type, estimate_name = "OR", 
                         exp = TRUE, ...)
  }
  glmfit_df = fit2df(glmfit, condense = FALSE, confint_type = confint_type, 
                     estimate_name = "OR", exp = TRUE, ...)
  df.out = finalfit_merge(factorlist, glmfit_df_c)
  df.out = finalfit_merge(df.out, glmfit_df, ref_symbol = "1.0")
  df.out$Total = stringr::str_remove(df.out$Total, " \\(.*\\)") %>% 
    as.numeric()
  df.out$Total[which(df.out$levels %in% c("Mean (SD)", "Median (IQR)"))] = dim(.data)[1]
  df.out$levels[which(df.out$levels %in% c("Mean (SD)", "Median (IQR)"))] = "-"
  if (any(is.na(df.out$label))) {
    remove_rows = which(is.na(df.out$label))
    df.out = df.out[-remove_rows, ]
  }else {
    df.out
  }
  df.out$levels = as.character(df.out$levels)
  df.out$fit_id = factor(df.out$fit_id, levels = df.out$fit_id[order(-df.out$index)])
  g1 = ggplot(df.out, aes(x = as.numeric(OR), xmin = as.numeric(L95), 
                          xmax = as.numeric(U95), y = fit_id)) + geom_errorbarh(height = 0.2) + 
    geom_vline(xintercept = 1, linetype = "longdash", colour = "black") + 
    geom_point(aes(size = Total), shape = 22, fill = "darkblue") + 
    scale_x_continuous(trans = "log10", breaks = breaks) + 
    xlab("Odds ratio (95% CI, log scale)") + theme_classic(11) + 
    theme(axis.title.x = element_text(), axis.title.y = element_blank(), 
          axis.text.y = element_blank(), axis.line.y = element_blank(), 
          axis.ticks.y = element_blank(), legend.position = "none")
  t1 = ggplot(df.out, aes(x = as.numeric(OR), y = fit_id)) + 
    annotate("text", x = column_space[1], y = df.out$fit_id, 
             label = df.out[, 2], hjust = 0, size = table_text_size) + 
    annotate("text", x = column_space[3], y = df.out$fit_id, 
             label = df.out[, 8], hjust = 1, size = table_text_size) + 
    theme_classic(14) + theme(axis.title.x = element_text(colour = "white"), 
                              axis.text.x = element_text(colour = "white"), axis.title.y = element_blank(), 
                              axis.text.y = element_blank(), axis.ticks.y = element_blank(), 
                              line = element_blank())
  if(print_level){
    t1 = t1 + annotate("text", x = column_space[2], y = df.out$fit_id, 
             label = df.out[, 3], hjust = 1, size = table_text_size) 
  }
  g1 = g1 + plot_opts
  t1 = t1 + table_opts
  title = plot_title(.data, dependent, dependent_label = dependent_label, 
                     prefix = prefix, suffix = suffix)
  gridExtra::grid.arrange(t1, g1, ncol = 2, widths = c(3, 2), 
                          top = grid::textGrob(title, x = 0.02, y = 0.2, gp = grid::gpar(fontsize = title_text_size), just = "left"))
}
```

```r
data(iris)
library(dplyr)
iris <- iris %>%
  mutate(setosa_on = ifelse(Species=="setosa", 1, 0),
         sl_5 = ifelse(Sepal.Length>5, ">5", "<= 5"))

iris %>%
  my_orplot("setosa_on", "sl_5",
          plot_opts=xlab("OR, 95% CI"),
          remove_ref=TRUE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-02-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i understand how it is built. in the or_plot function there is a table_opts option, so i thought it could be used to edit what's printed in the table.

Comment: @BPeif I updated the answer with the option of modifying the `or_plot()` function slightly and that will produce the answer you want, I think.

Comment: yes it is exactly what i finally did to avoid my problem and it works perfectly. I vote your answer as the the one solutioning my problem, but i'll still try to find another way to fix this more conveniently. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You could venture a bit into (not so) scary base R and create that regression model yourself. Gives you much more flexibility for plotting (and possibly for further analysis).

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

iris <- iris %>%
  mutate(setosa_on = ifelse(Species=="setosa", 1, 0),
         sl_5 = ifelse(Sepal.Length>5, ">5", "<= 5"))

mod <- glm(setosa_on~sl_5, family = "binomial", data= iris)
mod_df <- data.frame(exp(cbind(coef(mod), confint(mod))))[-1, ]
#> Waiting for profiling to be done...
names(mod_df) <- c("OR", "CI2.5", "CI97.5")

ggplot(mod_df, aes(y = "")) +
  geom_point(aes(x = OR), color = "darkblue", shape = 15, size = 3) +
  geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin = CI2.5, xmax = CI97.5), height = .2) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 1, lty = 2)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-02-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>